# kafka.api.OffsetRequest - unable to retrieve results

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

Am working through the task of determining **ConsumerLag** and need to retrieve the current Producer Offset as follows:

```
PartitionOffsetRequestInfo partitionOffsetRequestInfo = 
    new PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(OffsetRequest.LatestTime(), 100);

List<TopicAndPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < partitionMetadataList.size(); i++) {
    TopicAndPartition topicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(topic, i);
    partitions.add(topicAndPartition);

    tuple2List.add(new Tuple2<>(topicAndPartition, partitionOffsetRequestInfo));
}

Tuple2<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>[] tuple2Array =
    tuple2List.parallelStream().toArray(Tuple2[]::new);

WrappedArray<Tuple2<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>> wrappedArray =
    Predef.wrapRefArray(tuple2Array);

scala.collection.immutable.Map<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo> offsetRequestInfoMap =
    (scala.collection.immutable.Map<TopicAndPartition, PartitionOffsetRequestInfo>)
    scala.Predef$.MODULE$.Map().apply(wrappedArray);
    
OffsetRequest offsetRequest = new OffsetRequest(offsetRequestInfoMap, (short)0,
    0, OffsetRequest.DefaultClientId(), Request.OrdinaryConsumerId());
```

Looking at the **OffsetResponse** am presented with an array of `UnknownTopicOrPartitionException offsets`. If I pass in `(short)1` for the versionId (as I have for calls to **OffsetFetchResponse**) I get a `NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel` exception when I try to retrieve the results.

Questions:

a. Is there a better way to get current producer offset?
b. Why doesn't the **OffsetRequest** call work with VersionId = 1?

---

#### Edit:

Note that Im able to use this **channel** to retrieve ConsumerOffset so I know it works.

I can retrieve the values using the cmdline:

> kafka-consumer-groups  --bootstrap-server hostname:9092 --describe --new-consumer --group test_consumer

---

#### Edit:

Attempted to reuse sample scala (rewritten as Java) code:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = getConsumer();
List<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition>topicAndPartitions = new ArrayList<>();

org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition topicAndPartition = new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("my_topic", 0);
topicAndPartitions.add(topicAndPartition);

kafkaConsumer.assign(topicAndPartitions);

kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(topicAndPartitions);
long lPos = kafkaConsumer.position(topicAndPartition);
```

Got the same exception (`NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel`) when it got to the `.position()` call.

Comment: what's your final question then?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? There is a solution - I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code, current version for OffsetRequest is 0 not 1. Besides the source code does not return Version-1 response containing timestamp information as [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol) says. So it might be a doc bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you've come to this point here's a working solution:

```
private void getOffsets(String topic, String group) {
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = getConsumer(topic, group);
    List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos = kafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(topic);

    List<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition>topicAndPartitions = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < partitionInfos.size(); i++) {
        org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition topicAndPartition = new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition(topic, i);
        topicAndPartitions.add(topicAndPartition);
    }

    List<Long>startList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long>endList = new ArrayList<>();

    kafkaConsumer.assign(topicAndPartitions);

    for(int i = 0; i < partitionInfos.size(); i++) {
        OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadata = kafkaConsumer.committed(topicAndPartitions.get(i));
        if(offsetAndMetadata != null) {
            startList.add(offsetAndMetadata.offset());
        }
    }

    // did we find any active partitions?
    if(startList.size() == 0) {
        LOGGER.info("topic:group not found: {}:{}", topic, group);
        return;
    }

    kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(topicAndPartitions);

    for(int i = 0; i < partitionInfos.size(); i++) {
        endList.add(i, kafkaConsumer.position(topicAndPartitions.get(i)));
    }

    LOGGER.debug("startlist.size: {}  endlist.size: {}  partitions: {}", startList.size(), endList.size(), partitionInfos.size());

    long sumLag = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < partitionInfos.size(); i++) {
        long lStart = startList.get(i);
        long lEnd = endList.get(i);

        sumLag += (lEnd - lStart);

/*
 *  At this point Im sending the info to data dog. 
 *  The 'sum' value is nice to have.
 */
        LOGGER.debug("partition: {}  start: {}   end: {}  lag: {}", i, lStart, lEnd, (lEnd - lStart));
    }

    kafkaConsumer.poll(100);

    topicAndPartitions.clear();
    kafkaConsumer.assign(topicAndPartitions)

}
```